# Use of the word informed

Tags: word-usage

> Night Auditor David Snell informed that guest Christine Cane alleged a noise complaint on the 3rd floor.

Is the use of the word informed correct?

Comment: We do not allege a complaint.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't right. "Informed" is a transitive verb, so it requires an object, not just a subject. That is, you have to inform *someone* or *something*. You can't simply inform. So who did the night auditor inform of this problem? Who was he talking to?

Answer (score 1):

> Night Auditor David Snell informed that guest Christine Cane alleged a noise complaint on the 3rd floor.

I would argue that this is correct usage, 'informed' may be used in an intransitive context.  Implicit in the context of the sentence however is a third-party.  If contextually it is obvious whom David is informing of the complaint, then this is correct.

For a more formal, less short-hand way of writing this sentence, you may try;

> Night Auditor, David Snell, informed that guest Christine Cane alleged a noise complaint on the 3rd floor.

Both options are correct in UK English and would be easily understood by the reader.

Answer (score 0):

> > Night Auditor David Snell informed that guest Christine Cane alleged a noise complaint on the 3rd floor.

I would say this sounds like UK to me. I live in the US and "Night auditor" and odd use of "informed" to me. But what do I know about real English?!?

It sounds to me as if the sentence was ripped from a conversation between two people. So the night supervisor is handing off duty to the day supervisor. The night supervisor is doing a "Joe Friday" (from TV show dragnet) - "Just the facts ma'am."

So I read this as "Night Auditor David Snell reported that guest Christine Cane alleged a noise complaint on the 3rd floor."

Answer (score -1):

It is OK.  "***Inform***" can be used *in*transitively as well, see [this dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inform) or [that dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inform) for more information, or search for a phrase "*informs about*" or "*informs of*", for instance (use quotation marks).